# Problem related to Completeness : Is P = PC?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, np-complete

I am learning computational complexity. So, i took some practise problems from internet. I came across 1 problem which I am not sure whether my solution is correct or not. The question is :

Let us define a complexity class PC as follows : A decision problem A belongs to PC if and only if the following 2 conditions hold :

1) A belongs to P
2) For every problem B belongs to P, B is polynomial time reducible to A. Now we need to prove that PC = P.

My argument is that, PC is not equal to P. Because, this conditions are similar to NP-Complete conditions right. So, there are some problems in NP which are not NP-Complete right. So, NP is not equal to NP-Complete. Similarly, we can argue here that assuming C in PC is for completeness, P is not equal to PC.

Is my argument correct ? Please clarify me on this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. This is a question about the theory of computation.

Comment: The proof would hinge on whether every P problem is polynomial reducible to every other P problem. Your answer is an argument by analogy, which isn't a mathematically valid way of reasoning.

Comment: @PaulHankin Then only if the problem is P-Complete, every other problem in P will be reducible to it right. So, they maybe some problems in P which are not P-Complete. So PC is not equal to P right?

Comment: Note that polynomial time reductions are .. polynomial time. Normally you wouldn't use those to define PC, if you do then a funny thing happens: you should show that funny thing, and not just assume the answer by analogy to NP and NPC.

Comment: @harold I think I got it now. Correct me if I am wrong. They said that the problem in PC belongs to P. it means that there should exist a polynomial time solution for any problem that belongs to PC. So, that means entire set of PC collapses to P-Class. So, that’s why P = PC.